# Как сделать что бы значение переменной не сохранялось в callback_query_handler?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Когда пользователь первый раз нажимает на кнопку "Отказаться" бот удаляет сообщение и всё работает, но если ещё раз вызвать команду и нажать кнопку он пытается удалить сообщение которое было удалено при первом нажатии.
Как я понял id первого сообщение сохраняется в переменную msg и не заменяется на второе.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить, заранее спасибо

```
 @bot.message_handler(commands=['command'])
def command(message):

    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()                                                 
    accept = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Принять', callback_da = 'accept')
    refuse = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отказаться', callback_data = 'refuse')  
    kb.apd(accept, refuse)  
   
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat_id, "text", reply_markup=kb) 
                          
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def call(call):
                            
        if call.data == 'accept':   
            pass     
                                                                                                                                 
        elif call.data == 'refuse':
                               
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = msg.message_id, text = '❌')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, msg.message_id)
```

Comment: Оступы. Так и задумано?

Comment: @СергейШ Сделал что бы было удобней  читать код. Пробел в начале лишний, заметил только сейчас

Comment: Я про оступы, а не пробел. Как вы знаете в пайтоне оступы влияют на выполнения кода. У вас функция call внутри фунций command. А правельнее каждая независимая функция по отдельности со своими хендлерами.

Comment: @СергейШ Я пытался сделать что бы в функции call использовалась переменная из функции command, пока не очень понимаю как это сделать по другому

Answer (score 2):

Как написали выше, функция `call` не должна находиться внутри функции `command`.
Если хотите использовать переменную из одной функции в другой функции, можете использовать конструкцию `global`. Подробнее об этой конструкции можете почитать [здесь](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/opredelenie-funktsij-python/operatory-global-nonlocal/).